# Use "and" only between when there are 2 authors in Citation Style Files (csl)

Tags: citations, csl

I am preparing manuscript to journal named "annals of laboratory medicine" and for the reference part the instruction are as following

1. If the manuscript has only 2 authors, use “and” and not a comma between their names
2. For more 2 authors,use comma for all (including last 2 authors)

the expected results are

[Example 1]  Yang SJ, Shin MG, Kim SH, Cho D, Kee SJ, Shin JH, et al. Usefulness of Track-C (total HCV core antigen) assay in anti-HCV positive patients. Korean J Lab Med 2004;24:244-9. Kim HY. Recent advances of adult stem cell research. Korean J Lab Med 2003; 23(S1):S69-73.

[Example 2]  Sabbath KD, Ball ED, Larcom P, Davis RB, Griffin JD. Heterogeneity of clonogenic cells in acute myeloblastic leukemia. J Clin Invest 1985;75:746-53.

I tried editing style myself but couldn't set it as required
here is my setting

and the results were

[Example 3] Parsa AA and New MI.

[Example 4] Pignatelli D, Carvalho BL, Palmeiro A and Maçut D

The [Example 3] worked as expected. However, for the [Example 4], it put "and" between the last two authors instead of ","

From the documentation of "and" in the following link: https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#name
it is written that "and" specifies the delimiter between the *second to last and last* name of the names in a name variable. Still, what I want is using and only when there are exactly **two** authors. I cannot find the way to do this in the documentation

I also tried downloading and using the already made style from database (https://editor.citationstyles.org/styleInfo/?styleId=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotero.org%2Fstyles%2Fannals-of-laboratory-medicine)
but it still didnt work as expected

Could any one help me with this, please?

Comment: I'm afraid you are reading the documentation correctly. That's simply not possible. I don't believe it's ever come up as a requirement, either.